# How to change controller from view with json in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Hi I am new to angularjs I was wondering if were possible to send stuff that was already loaded in the view from json back to the controller.
What I am trying to do is to send the letters back to a controller and create a way to iterate over them with a intervale then change the style of each controller right now I am stuck because I can't get the ng-module="single" back to the interval controller name

Here is the view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" ng-app="App">
<body ng-controller="mainController"   ng-click="textArea = textArea + 1">
        <div ng-controller="clickController">
<div class="container">

            <div ng-controller="intervalController">

                <ul class="general_button"ng-repeat="letter in language[0].rows"> 
                    <button type="button" ng-model="single += single" class="btn btn-info" ng-repeat="single in letter"> 
                         {{single}}
                    </button>
                </ul>

                <div  >

                    <h1 ng-mousemove="textArea = textArea + 1">Mouse over me!</h1>

                    <label for="inputlg">input-lg</label>
                    <input class="form-control input-lg" id="inputlg" type="text" value="{{ textArea }}">
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here are the controllers

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);
var theLanguage = 'english';
App.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http,$log) {
  $http.get(theLanguage + '.json')
       .then(function(res){
          $scope.language = res.data;                
        });
$log.debug('Hello Debug!');
});

App.controller('intervalController', function($scope, $log) {
    this.$log = $log;
    var name = $scope.single;

    $log.log(name);
  $log.log('Hello World!');

});

App.controller('clickController', function($scope) {

});
```

and here is the Json

```
[{
    "rows":[[
        "a",
        "e",
        "u",
        "i",
        "o",
        "y"
    ],
    [
        "b",
        "c",
        "d",
        "f",
        "g"
    ],
    [
        "h",
        "i",
        "j",
        "k",
        "l"
    ],
    [
        "m",
        "n",
        "p",
        "q",
        "r"
    ],
    [
        "s",
        "t",
        "v",
        "w",
        "x z"
    ]
]}]
```

Thank you in advance for your help any suggestions about how to do this a better way would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad idea to try to set ng-model and ng-repeat on the same element. You have the model already, letter. Letter is bound to the view, so anything the user changes in letter will be accessible in the controller. You should be able to just remove

```
ng-model="single += single"
```

And then interate over letter inside the controller:

```
angular.forEach($scope.letter, function(single) {
    //do something with single
});
```

Comment: I tried adding angular.forEach($scope.letter, function(single) {
 $log.log(single);
    }); but it didn't seem to work